# How do I encode an image asset as a base64 data URI in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an image asset in the `private` directory of my Meteor project, and I need to encode the image into a data URI.

I know that I load the file using `Assets.getBinary`, but what's the best way to base64 encode that file?

Answer (score 2):

Meteor actually has a built-in base64 package, although it's not added by default.

Add the package by calling `meteor add base64`.

Then a data URI can be created like this:

```
var binaryImage = Assets.getBinary('pdf-logo.png');
var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,' + Base64.encode(binaryImage);
```